# How to set keyboard background in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, background

This might sound stupid, but I'm seriously a newbie at Android programming.
I have looked this up on the Internet, but it looks like nobody ever had difficulties with this. 
I am making a soft keyboard for our school Android project.
I intended to make my own background for this keyboard, but I couldn't figure out how to change the keyboard's background.
I made a buttonbgselector.xml file in my drawable dir:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
<item
android:state_checkable="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
<item
android:state_checkable="true"
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
<item
android:state_checkable="true"
android:state_checked="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
<item
android:state_checkable="true"
android:state_checked="true"
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed" />
</selector>
```

I tried setting the background here:

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {
    mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.input, null);
    mInputView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonbgselector);
    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    return mInputView;
}
```

And the keys are still the same, nothing changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a XML-Attribute called [keyBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:keyBackground).
Just set this attribute to a drawable and it should be fine.

Add this attrbute to the KeyboardView in *input.xml*:

```
<KeyboardView android:keyBackground="@drawable/buttonbgselector" .../>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but sadly, that didn't work. I wonder if it's my png image that is the cause