# How to change default soft keyboard background color?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, soft-keyboard

I want to know how to change default soft keyboard background color ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of default keyboard used in an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896287/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-default-keyboard-used-in-an-app)

Comment: you can create your own custom keyboard

Comment: from here http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Comment: create custom keyboard : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: I do not want to create custom one, I need a original one

Answer (score 0):

There is a XML-Attribute called keyBackground. Just set this attribute to a drawable and it will change image for the key. This image needs to be a StateListDrawable, with the following possible states: normal, pressed, checkable, checkable+pressed, checkable+checked, checkable+checked+pressed.

Add this attrbute to the [KeyboardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) in xml:

```
<KeyboardView android:keyBackground="@drawable/whatever_you_want />
```

See this [tutorial](http://burnignorance.com/android-apps-development/setting-keyboard-key-background-image/)