# Change label's color android keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-canvas

I have to change default color of KeyboardView from white to black,how can I edit that?

I tried with define a key_style, but I have button not regular, so I need to set an image how background...

Comment: Have a look at these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789997/how-to-change-background-color-of-key-for-android-soft-keyboard  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096395/how-to-set-keyboard-background-in-android

Comment: yes, both already red... But these link are to change background (that I know is difficult), I want to change color of label. letters are now white, I would change these in black..